# vueJS, timeout not wating for timer

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to setup a simple timeout in vue.JS but somehow it seems that the waiting time is not working as my `parse` function is triggered immediately instead of 5 seconds later

```
props: {
        url:String
    },
    data(){
        return{
            typingTimer:null,
            doneTypingInterval: 5000
        }
    },
methods: {
        parseTimeout(url){
            clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
            this.typingTimer = setTimeout(
                this.parse(url),
                this.doneTypingInterval
            );
        },
        parse(url){
           console.log('triggered')
        },
},
watch: {
    url(){
        this.parseTimeout(this.$props.url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `this.parse(url)`
but you need to pass function 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

```
          this.typingTimer = setTimeout(
           () => this.parse(url),
            this.doneTypingInterval
        );
```